# Cassandra concurrent requests

Tags: python, cassandra

I am trying to make concurrent requests to cassandra database on a single thread using execute_async() method in python code. According to the documentation it can handle at least 100 queries on a single connection but my throughput starts falling even if increase the concurrency more than 4. Can anyone tell me any reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're trying to reimplement the async callback pattern.

Use the **cassandra.concurrent.execute_concurrent()** to get the performance of the async callback chaining (read [here](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/concurrent.html#cassandra.concurrent.execute_concurrent))

Comment: Thank you for the link but I have tried that also  In that case also I get concurrency=4 as the best case for throughput although we can have atleast 100 concurrent requests.